# Getting wrong data on join table

Tags: php, postgresql

**Well let’s supposed that I have the table horarios with data inside**

```
     grdid |    curso    | disciplina | professor
-----------+------------------+-----------------+------------
       231 |  Engenharia |        6   |       2
       120 |  Enfermagem |        1   |       5
```

**And on another table called disciplinas I have the following data**

```
      departamento | codigocurso | codigo | disciplina
-------------------+-----------------+-----------+------------
               100 |        120 |      1 | numero1
               100 |       2121 |      2 | numero2
               100 |       2121 |      3 | numero3
               200 |        231 |      4 | numero4
               200 |        231 |      5 | numero5
               200 |        231 |      6 | numero6
```

With the data that I have inside those tables, by making the join table just like on the codes bellow I am supposed to get the numero6 right? But unfortunately I am getting the numero2 and and I tried to insert another data on table horarios but on the join table is displaying numero5.
What am I doing wrong?

```
for ($i=0; $i< pg_numrows ($res);$i++){
  echo '<table style="font-size:12px;" bgcolor=white width=1027px><tr>';
  $curso=pg_result ($res, $i , "curso");      
  $sql2="select horarios.dias, horarios.inicio, horarios.fim, disciplinas.disciplina, professore1.nomehorario, horarios.sala from horarios
    left outer join disciplinas on (horarios.professor = disciplinas.codigo)
    left outer join professore1 on (horarios.professor = professore1.numero)
    where curso='$curso' order by dias;";
```

Comment: Why do you JOIN the `disciplinas` table based on the `professor` column, surely it should JOIN on the `disciplina` column? As you have it, neither of the sample rows on `horarios` would point to professor 6, as far as I can see, or am I missing something? The first row points at 2, the second at 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join condition is wrong. You should use the `disciplina` column for it:

```sql
select horarios.dias, horarios.inicio, horarios.fim, disciplinas.disciplina, professore1.nomehorario, horarios.sala from horarios
left outer join disciplinas on (horarios.disciplina = disciplinas.codigo)
-- Here ---------------------------------^
left outer join professore1 on (horarios.professor = professore1.numero)
where curso='$curso' order by dias
```